# Adding Elements of generic list to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, generic-list

I have a generic list `List<String, String> ListName`

I am trying to insert the values of the list, into a dictionary `Dictionary<String, int>`

I looked at places but only found adding elements of dictionary to list. While my requirement is opposite. I tried using toDictionary, but it didnt work for me. Not sure what went wrong.

Have anyone every attempted inserting values from list to dictionary?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Which `List` takes two type parameters?  Where does the `int` come from?

Comment: The list is generic, and reads a file which contains three fields, and one of them is int. so attempt here is to use a string column and the int column as key and value.

Comment: The BCL generic List is defined as `List<T>`, not `List<T,U>`.  So you could not make a `List<string,string>` using the BCL.  We cannot see howyou are storing the three fields from the file.  Please show some code.

Comment: Show some code of what you are trying.

Comment: We have no idea of what you are trying to do. Secondly C# base class library defines `List<T>` and not `List<T1, T2>`. Thirdly how is the string in `Dictionary` related to `int` in the generics?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean `List<string[]>` because I have never seen a generic `List<T,WhoAmI>` before

If you are using `List<string[]>` you can use the `ToDictionary` function

```
List<string[]> ListName = new List<string[]>();
ListName.Add(new[] { "Stack", "1" });
ListName.Add(new[] { "Overflow", "2" });

// Select the first string([0]) as the key, and parse the 2nd([1]) as int
Dictionary<string,int> result = ListName.ToDictionary(key => key[0], value => int.Parse(value[1]));
```

if you are using some kind of custom object in your list you can also do it the same way

```
List<MyObject<string, string>> ListName = new List<MyObject<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, int> result = ListName.ToDictionary(key => key.String1, value => int.Parse(value.String2));


public class MyObject<T, U>
{
    public MyObject(T string1, U string2)
    {
        String1 = string1;
        String2 = string2;
    }

    public T String1 { get; set; }
    public U String2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** You should add error checking around the `int.Parse` or use `Int.TryParse` if there is a chance it may not be a number.

Comment: my code is pretty much like sa_ddam213 mentioned

List<MyObject<string, string>> ListName = new List<MyObject<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, int> result = ListName.ToDictionary(key => key.String1, value => int.Parse(value.String2));


public class MyObject<T, U>
{
    public MyObject(T string1, U string2, int v)
    {
        String1 = string1;
        String2 = string2;
    }

    public T String1 { get; set; }
    public U String2 { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that:

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> ListName = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>();
Dictionary<String, Int32> dict = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
ListName.ForEach(e=> dict.Add(e.key, Int32.Parse(e.Value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where the integer is coming from, but something like this should work:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
list.ForEach(x => dict.Add(x, theInteger));
```